# Linq to entity select items and give id

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have a table example you can see below

```
ID Name         Value

3  NameOne      ValueOne    
7  NameTwo      ValueTwo    
10 NameThree    ValueThree
```

I need to select with Linq to Entity and get results as you can see in example below:

```
ItemID ItemName 

1      NameOne       
2      NameTwo         
3      NameThree
```

Comment: What did you come up with yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Linq;

var list = context.TableName.OrderBy(a => a.ID).Select(a => new { a.Name }).ToList().Select((a, index) => new { ItemID = index + 1, ItemName = a.Name } );
```

`context.TableName.OrderBy(a => a.ID).Select(a => new { a.Name }).ToList()` - this part takes name list

`Select((a, index) => new { ItemID = index + 1, ItemName = a.Name } );` - this part adds index (ItemID)